# Should closing off-topic question require reasoning/feedback?

Tags: discussion, moderation, off-topic

When questions are asked but deemed off-topic by the community and subsequently closed, should there be a requirement for reasoning and constructive feedback before voting to close?

Comment: I usually leave a comment why the question is off-topic, and where it should be posted/migrated to if possible.

Comment: It would be nice if people politely explained why they voted to close, but no, not required.

Comment: I'm not downvoting to try to avoid you thinking that meta is all about gang downvoting. However, if you have a question about why your question was closed it's best to actually ask that question rather than coming up with a feature request to force people to do yet more things and then labelling it as a discussion... Votes mean something different on meta, they can just express disagreement, see the [faq].

Comment: @greg I assume this was sparked by [this question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877022/angularjs-routing-and-seo-crawling)? If so, feel free to ask a specific Meta question about it.

Comment: @Bart see below comment against the answer. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is necessary. In the majority of cases, the closure message and the FAQ linked to in that message do an adequate job of explaining the motivation behind the closure. Now if only people would actually read it. But that's another matter altogether.

That said, especially with newer users or other special cases, I do sometimes leave a comment explaining my motivation behind a vote to close. Perhaps not so often for off-topic though. More often for "not a real question", since that one seems to lead to quite a lot of confusion. (Hey, this thing has a question mark at the end. How is it not a real question?).

Should you as the OP be terribly confused about the reason, then by all means take it to Meta. If you constructively ask for the motivation behind the closure, you will more than likely get an in-depth explanation. If you're still in the hot steaming "What The F" mood, you might want to give it some time, since rants are not often responded to in a positive way. But if you're simply curious, please do ask.

Comment: Ok I think I've misunderstood SOMeta a little! Yes I raised this Q in response to one of my SO questions but thought questions on here should be more generic. Didn't know they could be as specific as you mention. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Greg That is no problem at all. There is even a tag for it: [specific-question].